# Why is twitter4j TwitterStream not filtering user's tweets?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying to stream a single user's tweets with twitter4j. Why is this TwitterStream not working? I've seen tweets come through that are replies to the intended user's tweets, but not the intended user's tweets.

```
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " : " + status.getText());
    }
    @Override
    public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {}

    @Override
    public void onStallWarning(StallWarning stallWarning) {}

    public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
    public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
    public void onException(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
};

TwitterStreamFactory tsf = new TwitterStreamFactory(getConfiguration()); // this is working fine, with OAuth, tokens, secrets, etc.
TwitterStream twitterStream = tsf.getInstance();
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery(1234567890L);

twitterStream.filter(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided code seems to be correct. We are using a similar setup for a large deployment in production.

Are you sure, that the account is not marked as **private**? Tweets from such accounts are not returned by the Twitter API.

The underlying endpoint used by twitter4j is the filter realtime API.

The `follow` parameter is described [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters). The documentation states:

> **follow**
>
> A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose
> Tweets should be delivered on the stream. Following protected users is
> not supported.
>
> **For each user specified, the stream will contain:**
>
> - Tweets created by the user.
> - Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
> - Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
> - Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
> - Manual replies, created without pressing a reply
>   button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).
>
> **The stream will not contain:**
>
> - Tweets mentioning the user (e.g. “Hello @twitterapi!”).
> - Manual Retweets created without pressing a Retweet button (e.g. “RT
>   @twitterapi The API is great”).
> - Tweets by protected users.

In addition, the stream operates on a "moving window" and tracks the user at real-time. Thus, you cannot use it to retrieve a tweet, which was posted by the user before your Twitter stream was connected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks; the account IS private, but I'm using the same credentials as other twitter4j code which has been able to get these tweets via getUserTimeline(); I'm currently polling for this user's tweets, and I'm trying to change it to streaming

Comment: Timeline is a different endpoint. Check https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline - this endpoint can retrieve Tweets from protected accounts (under certain circumstances). However, streaming api cannot (as stated above).